# For loops with lists?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm starting to code in python and I came across this code snippet:

```
for [x, y] in L:
    for ix in range(-1, 2):
        for iy in range(-1, 2):
            cir = pylab.Circle((x + ix, y + iy), radius=sigma,  fc='r')
            pylab.gca().add_patch(cir)
```

at the line 1 I can not understand what is happening because I had never seen anything like it in another programming language. How this works?

```
for [x, y] in L:
```

[x, y] is a list? i dont know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `[x, y]` is a list with two elements. For your loop to work, `L` must be a list (or other iterable data structure) that contains a bunch of lists with two elements. Each time through the loop one of those lists is copied into `[x, y]`, then the individual values of `x` and `y` are used in the body of the loop.

Try this and see if it makes sense:

```
L = [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ]

for [x, y] in L:
    print x
    print y
```

Comment: Haha so simple. Thanks

Comment: Brackets are unnecessary as well.  `for x,y in L:` works.

Comment: @MarkTolonen has difference between [ x, y ] , x, y and ( x, y ) ?

Answer (score 1):

L must be a sequence of lists (or tuples) with two elements, which can be iterated over. So whenever for [x,y] in L: is executed, it picks each item in th sequence one by one and enters into the loop.

let the sequence be  `L = [[2,3], [4,5], ['Jeff', 7]]`
Now here what will happen when `for [x,y] in L:` will be executed is :- first list in the sequence [2,3] will be picked up and assigned as `x` and `y` respectively. And in the next iteration `x` and `y` will get the value 4 & 5 respectively. Like wise in third iteration `x` will be `Jeff` and `y` will be 7.

```
L = [[2,3], [4,5], ['Jeff', 7]]
count = 0
for [x,y] in L:
    count += 1
    print " Iteration :- %d, \t x :- %s, \t y:- %s" %(count, str(x), str(y))
```